# Change Windows 7 64 bit to 32 bit to run legacy programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a convenient way to side grade my Windows 7 Professional  64 bit to 32bit. I need to do that in order to use some 32bit legacy programs. I am on a Dell OptiPlex 780 Desktop.

Comment: There is not a single 32-bit application that can't work on a 64-bit version of windows

Comment: Actually, you probably need to run *16* bit legacy programs. Most 32 but programs are compatible with 64 bit versions of Windows. However, the 64 bit versions drop backwards compatibility with 16 bit executables (compatibility which 32 versions of Windows maintain)

Answer (score 2):

Short of uninstalling the current OS and installing the desired one...there is no way to downgrade.

Side-notes / alternatives:

- tinkering with the compatibility settings of the executables (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-programs-run#1TC=windows-7)...this is the first thing I'd try to. Since you are not trying to run 16-bit programs on the 64-bit OS, there's a good possibility that it'll work;
- Virtual Machine w/ the desired OS on it;
- multiple OS setup (have the 32-bit one installed along with the current one).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "sidegrade" to from 64bit to 32bit. However, Windows 7 license keys are not 32bit or 64bit specific, if you are able to get your hands on a 32bit disc you can use your current key with it as long as they are both retail versions of Windows. If your computer came with Windows 7 pre-installed then you'll run into OEM license issues, and won't be able to activate.